# Sorting a formatted LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

A sequence of non-empty strings stringList is given, containing only uppercase letters of the Latin alphabet. For all strings starting with the same letter, determine their total length and obtain a sequence of strings of the form "S-C", where S is the total length of all strings from stringList that begin with the character C. **Order the resulting sequence in descending order of the numerical values of the sums, and for equal values of the sums, in ascending order of the C character codes.**

This question is related to one of my previous questions.

One solution that works is this one:

```
stringList.GroupBy(x => x[0]).Select(g => $"{g.Sum(x => x.Length)}-{g.Key}");
```

The problem is that with this given example I don't know where to add the OrderByDescending()/ThenBy() clauses in order to get the correctly sorted list.

Answer (score 2):

Create an intermediate data structure to store needed info and use it for sorting and then building the output:

```cs
stringList
    .GroupBy(x => x[0])
    .Select(g => (Length: g.Sum(x => x.Length), Char: g.Key))
    .OrderByDescending(t => t.Length)
    .ThenBy(t => t.Char)
    .Select(t => $"{t.Length}-{t.Char}");
```

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. The cleanest way of doing it would be to make a more complex object with the properties you care about, use those to sort, then keep only what you want in the output. Like:

```
stringList
    .GroupBy(x => x[0])
    .Select(g => new {
        Len = g.Sum(x => x.Length),
        Char = g.Key,
        Val = $"{g.Sum(x => x.Length)}-{g.Key}"
    })
    .OrderByDescending(x => Len)
    .ThenBy(x => x.Char)
    .Select(x => x.Val);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `Select` after the `GroupBy` to transform the groups into an anonymous object containing the things you want to sort by. Then you can use `OrderByDescending` and `ThenBy` to sort. After that, `Select` the formatted string you want:

```
stringList.GroupBy(x => x[0]) // assuming all strings are non-empty
    .Select(g => new {
        LengthSum = g.Sum(x => x.Length),
        FirstChar = g.Key
    })
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.LengthSum)
    .ThenBy(x => x.FirstChar)
    .Select(x => $"{x.LengthSum}-{x.FirstChar}");
```

Alternatively, do it in the query syntax with `let` clauses, which I find more readable:

```
var query = from str in stringList
    group str by str[0] into g
    let lengthSum = g.Sum(x => x.Length)
    let firstChar = g.Key
    orderby lengthSum descending, firstChar
    select $"{lengthSum}-{firstChar}";
```